# TFS 2017 Release Mangagement - Tracking Release Status

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have been trying out TFS 2017 on Prem Release Management.

For the most part I like it.  I am having some frustrations with managing the status of each release.

There is an indicator in the overview panel to show if each environment's been deployed to (successful, failed, or in progress).  That's fine, but how to we track the state of the overall release?

Customer's are fickle.  I can have a customer ask me to delay a release, with a detailed explanation as to why. I can have our infrastructure team put our release on hold as well.  I can think of several different status indicators for the release over all to track this information: TFS 2017 from what I can see does not track any of this.

Why not?  Is tracking the status of each release not important?  Am I just using the tools ineffectively?

I have managers who want to know what's going on with a release.  They don't want to know what environment's are done, they want to know what's going on at a project level.  I would imagine some sort of work item is in order here...

Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you have your own requirements around release tracking that exceed the capabilities of the product. You could write an extension to cover these requirements, or submit a UserVoice item to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that you want to track the release like the process of Code Review/Pull request, introduce the communication process for release management. Record the comments/reasons for team communication and start the release when all the contributes agreed and approved.

There isn't such a mechanism introduced for now, you can Abandon/Delete the release and start new release if needed. You can track each release under the Release tab.

Whatever, you could submit the **User Voice item** to suggest the features you want: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services

[image]